# Spider/Robot UserAgent Detection C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-agent

I'm working on an application that redirects users to upgrade browser if they are not on our browser list.

My goal is to create an exception to detect if they are a crawler, based on their `UserAgent` string.

At this point, I'm getting the a message ..."no definition or extension method for .ToLower"

Here is my code:

```
    private bool IsValidCrawler(HttpRequestBase request)
    {
        bool isCrawler = true;

        switch (request.Browser.Crawler.ToLower())  
        {
            case "googlebot":
            case "bingbot":
            case "yahoo!":
            case "facebookexternalhit":
            case "facebookplatform":
                break;
        }

        return isCrawler;
    }
```

Can anyone point me to where I have gone wrong?

Comment: As others have mentioned, `Crawler` is a `bool` type. This means you probably won't be able to use your own list of crawlers to check against, since this is already determined for you by this property internally.

Comment: _"I'm very new to C#, so please dont down vote me too much."_. - Just a tip for the next time: do some research. Your question doesn't show you're trying to understand the error or that you looked up the manual for the methods and properties you're using. :-)

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to clarify, this is my first programming language, and I was stuck, I had looked at the manual, and was lost, I've spent the last hour working with this. But thanks for the advice.

Comment: For your question, you dont need to create your method, just check  the request.Browser.Crawler. It will return true if it is crawler else false.

Comment: The documentation can be plenty confusing when you are new to it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for the Crawler property (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpcapabilitiesbase.crawler(v=vs.110).aspx) you'll notice it's a boolean type.

The property itself will let you know if the request is coming from a known crawler. You can try the following for the time being. Leaving the method so you don't have to change too much.

```
private bool IsValidCrawler(HttpRequestBase request)
{
    bool isCrawler = request.Browser.Crawler;

    return isCrawler;
}
```

Comment: why at first the need to create function when you have already had the property?

Comment: It allows any code written against the method to continue working without modification while testing the viability of the implementation. I would eventually remove the method, but only after I've confirmed that it meets all of my use cases.

Comment: Where does Microsoft Keep the list of known crawlers?  How do they get added to the list?

Answer (score 0):

There are thousands of crawlers, the user agent parser included .NET framework is able to handle only few of them and it doesn't keep an updated list of them.

Install [this](https://nuget.org/packages/OrbintSoft.Yauaa.NetStandard) .nuget package, it provides a semantic parser and the library is very active.

You can initialize the parser with this code:

```
public static class YauaaSingleton
{
    private static UserAgentAnalyzer.UserAgentAnalyzerBuilder Builder { get; }

    private static readonly Lazy<UserAgentAnalyzer> analyzer = new Lazy<UserAgentAnalyzer> (() => Builder.Build());

    public static UserAgentAnalyzer Analyzer
    {
        get
        {
            return analyzer.Value;
        }
    }

    static YauaaSingleton()
    {
        Builder = UserAgentAnalyzer.NewBuilder();
        Builder.DropTests();
        Builder.DelayInitialization();
        Builder.WithCache(100);
        Builder.HideMatcherLoadStats();
        Builder.WithAllFields();
    }
}
```

Then very easy:

```
  private bool IsValidCrawler(HttpRequestBase request)
  {
      var ua = YauaaSingleton.Analyzer.Parse(request.UserAgent);
      var devideClass = UserAgentClassifier.GetDeviceClass(ua);
      if (devideClass == DeviceClass.Robot || devideClass == DeviceClass.RobotMobile || devideClass == DeviceClass.RobotImitator)
          return true;
      return false;
  }
```

**Robot**: Normal crawler
**RobotMobile**: A crawler that emulates a mobile device
**RobotImitator**: This is not a crawler, but something that emulates a crawler

if you want you can also use:

`var isHuman = UserAgentClassifier.IsHuman(ua);` In this case you handle also hacked user agents and other cases.